# MySQL UPDATE and INSERT both returning error message about bad syntax, but it is correct syntax when trying it on phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a PHP program that will either INSERT a new row, or UPDATE the existing one if it's already there.  When running on a browser, it returns errors.

But, the actual call runs OK on phpMySQL - no error reported and row is updated.

```
"Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"updated", `conditions` ="    ",' at line 1.
```

Code to connect to mySQL and make the update or insert is very simple

```
        require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');

        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error($dbcon); 

            exit ;
            }
```

Then I make the actual body of the call, which produces variable $call containing this (example is for UPDATE):

```
UPDATE `deal` SET `deal_lotus_source` = "updated", `conditions` ="  ", `termsnotes` = " ", `walkprovision` = " ", `sector` = "Application Software", `industry` = "Airconditioning", `tgt` = "Bcd", `acq` = "E", `dtstart` = "2015/03/08" , `dtclose` = "2015/03/23", `dtexdivtgt` = "2015/03/17", `dtexdivacq` = "2015/03/17", `dtexdivtgtexp` = "2015/03/17", `dtexdivacqexp` = "2015/03/17", `acq` = "E",`stat`= "Closed",`acqtype`= "Domestic",`dealtype`= "Acquisition of Private Company Cash-Stoc",`analyst`= "Fred Blogs",`tgttkr`= "ABC",`tgtx`= "C",`tgtprec`= "$",`tgtpret`= "1",`tgtshrout`= "2",`acqtkr`= "D",`acqx`= "F",`acqprec`= "$",`acqpret`= "3",`acqshrsout`= "4",`dlvalue`= "5",`eacls`= "Actual",`tgtlaw`= "",`acqlaw`= "",`tgtbank`= "",`acqbank`= "",`tgtshrsoutfd`= "6",`acqshrsoutfd`= "7",`tgtdebt`= "8",`acqdebt`= "8",`suppress`= "0",`pricingp`= "",`terminate`= " ",`divstattgt`= "",`divstatacq`= "",`divfreqtgt`= "Quarterly",`divfreqacq`= "Quarterly",`divcurrtgt`= "$",`divcurracq`= "$",`divamttgt`= "0.000",`divamtacq`= "0.000", `cos` = "", `mot` = "" WHERE deal_id =578
```

and the code to update (or insert) is

```
if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $call)) {
                    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbcon));
                    die;
                }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use single quotes arround the values:

```
UPDATE `deal` SET `deal_lotus_source` = 'updated', `conditions` ='  ', `termsnotes` = ' ', `walkprovision` = ' ', `sector` = 'Application Software', ...
```

Comment: But only because the op has used double quotes to define the boundaries of the query string, right?

Comment: That;s a problem if input from user contains single quotes (eg world's).  I changed over to double quotes surrounding strings, because I can't control what users enter - they may use 'world' or "world" or "world's" etc.  I am passing the strings through mysqli_real_escape_string to convert " to \", so that wrapping with double-quote should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes in PHP can be confusing, because depending on which type of quote you use there are (different rules](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/phpTutorial/quotes.htm). The most important things (in this case) to keep in mind are these 2:
* If you have a variable ($var) inside double-quotes (`"$var"`) then it will get substituted (your string will now contain `value`) whereas if it is in single-quotes (`'$var'`) then it will NOT get substituted (it remains in your string as `$var`)
* If you are need single-quotes as part of your string then use double-quotes around the string. (`"I don't like contractions and I can't bear to use them."`) If you need double-quotes as part of your string then use single quotes to surround the string. (`'He said, "Hello, Dear!" and she slapped him.'`)

You are using double quotes (note the values you want to compare `conditions` and `termsnotes` and etc. to) but you are going to want to change to single-quotes inside the string so you can surround the whole thing with double-quotes. This also has the advantage of allowing you to use variables inside it.

```
$call = "UPDATE `deal` 
    SET `deal_lotus_source` = 'updated', 
        `conditions` ='  ', 
        `termsnotes` = ' ', 
        `walkprovision` = ' ', 
        ...
        `mot` = '' 
    WHERE deal_id =578";
```

Note that the *only* double-quotes in that whole line of code are the ones at the very beginning and ending of the string. If you want to put a double-quote *inside* the string then you would have to put a backslash in front of it.

One very important step when you are constructing a query in a string (especially if you are getting errors with it) is to actually look at it. Use `echo "call=<pre>$call</pre><br />\n";` and then look very carefully at all your quotes and etc.  You can actually copy/paste the results of this echo into phpMyAdmin and see if the actual query works in your sql tab - this is a great test.

In summary, quotes in PHP are very consistent and very powerful, but they do have the potential to change your string during the process of assigning the string to a variable. It's very important to verify that the string *after assignment* is the string that you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but so far it's not helping.  I tried the extra examination of the $call that you suggest, but the two lines are identical.  For me, the issue remains why is fails from inside the browser call, but phpMyAdmin says it''s OK!

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the *exact* line of code where `$call` is set to your query?

Comment: Can I confirm that you actually copy/pasted the line from the browser into phpMyAdmin? Comparing the 2 lines just by reading them can result in things looking identical, but perhaps an ever-so-slight difference in the type of quote (smart-quotes or something) can make a big difference. Can you confirm that you actually used copy/paste? It would actually be good to view the source of the page and to copy straight from the HTML source to be 100% sure.